# How to create new application from existing code base copy

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to android development. I want to create a new application using the existing application code. Here I did-

1. Copied complete source code into new folder.
2. Opened in eclipse by creating new workspace.
3. Changed app_name label to new application name.

Installed application into device, but it is overriding the existing application with new application name i.e. configured in the 3rd step.

Can anyone point me to the right path to install new application instead of overriding the existing application.

Comment: Why don't you jump import the working project into your IDE and then modify it to suit your needs?

Comment: Here my question is to install new application into device without overriding the existing application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the package name of your copied source code, and you will be ready to go. Package name is unique for each application in Android. So, if you don't change it, everything else will be over-written, since your phone will consider it as the same application.

Comment: Along with unique package name, we have to maintain unique value for "android:authorities" attribute in provider tag in manifest file for content providers.

Otherwise you will get an error like - "Can't install because provider name newapp.xxxx (in package newapp.xxxx) is already used by oldapp.xxxx".